# Inserting text into UITextField on tvOS in a Xcode Cloud UI-Test

Tags: swift, tvos, xcode-ui-testing, xcode-cloud

I am running a UI-Test on Xcode Cloud for a tvOS application (Apple TV), and part of the test includes a text insertion. Since Xcode Cloud automatically provides me with screenshots for every user interaction I can observe that nothing is inserted into the UITextField and this is my issue.
The functions that I use are:

```
// repeated for completing a string sequence
XCUIRemote.shared.press(.right) // left, up and down 
..
..
XCUIRemote.shared.press(.select)
```

The screenshots capture focus movement between keys on the keyboard but executing the select action does not seem to work. This UI-test works locally on Xcode on my Macbook but this does not work in Xcode Cloud.

Comment: Please add the code for text insertion

Comment: Text insertion is done manually with the Apple TV Remote.

Comment: Why do you manually insert text on UITest?

Comment: Your point is very relevant from an automation standpoint, but the issue here is why the select action is not performed.